# Clicking on an ignored tag shows no results

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

If I click on one of my ignored tags or search for it (by typing "[tagname]" in the search box), there are no results. Obviously, the results are hidden since this tag is ignored. However, it would be useful to show the results in this case, since I am specifically asking for them.

As I recall, it actually used to work this way.

Comment: Write a greasemonkey script!  The html is still there i believe, the style is just set to display 'none'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, as long as we are setting parameters on what exactly we are talking about.

When you put a tag in your *ignored* section, it makes both literal and intuitive sense that any questions tagged that way are now **ignored**. Forever and for always.

However, there is one case that makes sense to create an 'exception'. If you search for something that is literally a tagname, it makes sense to me that you would want to receive results from that tag. If you do a search that doesn't include any tagnames, then your regular *ignore* rules will apply. If you want to be more pedantic, you could include a tag specifier, so even if I ignore "java" then searching for "getters tag:java" would retrieve results that are tagged java, even if it is ignored.

For us programmers, this is a matter of scope. The smaller scopes should trump the larger ones. Ignored tags are preferences, that is, they are a general scope. When I am searching I have a much more specific scope.

If I have "java" in my ignored tags, it is because I do not want to see Java question, but when I search for "java" we can assume two things. Either the user knows best, and she/he *does in fact* want results with java. Or we can 'protect' the user from what they don't want by excluding *specifically what they asked for*. Obviously, any search that excludes the specific nouns of the search phrase has some sort of problem.

In sum: **If the user searches for a specific tag, then we include answers that have that tag, even if that tag has an 'ignore' on it.**

Answer (score 3):

If you're ignoring it, *how do you know it's even there?* eh? eh?

Comment: Good point. BTW - we need more java questions on SO. There are none. I checked. :)

Comment: All of the questions with my ignored tags just look like ghost questions...

Comment: @Andy Mikula: you can set it in your prefs to completely hide ignored tags.

Comment: I know it's there because all the answers appear for about three seconds before disappearing.  Personally, I just clicked on the [c#] *in my ignored list* to ask, "So what are all these C# questions I've ignored up until now?"  The first page out of 2774 appears briefly, but then all the questions disappear, because they're ignored!  Excitingly I can still click on the page numbers to select any of the 2774 blank pages.

Answer (score 2):

Another question about this is - if you are ignoring the tag and the page with url `stackoverflow.com/tags/<ignoredtag>` does show nothing, then why do you have a *clickable* list of ignored in the first page (each button is linked to an empty page)

Answer (score 1):

Disabling and enabling the tags is *not* a solution.

*Stackoverflow* is a programming site, I would expect it to automate tedious tasks. I would have both a blacklist for tags that hides all questions and a graylist that only hides questions that do not contain favourite tags. And visibility shouldn't apply when you search for the tag that triggers the black list!

As it is now, it is as if the library version of `quicksort` returned the original array and told you to read its members in order by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Take the tag off of ignore and then add it back when you are done.

Comment: Common sense FTW.

Comment: .WTF esnes nommoC

Comment: Isn't this basically 'it hurts when I do this' - 'stop doing that'?

Comment: tuwlol :yugnnj@

Comment: @Rich, I dunno...just bored at work.

Comment: @Andy: See also: "Use some common sense".

Comment: Makes a lot more sense to me than rigging the tag ignoring feature so that it only ignores part of the time.

Comment: @jjnguy: idk my bff jill

Comment: Really, this solution makes sense.  You told the system that you didn't want to see things containing that tag.  So it is keeping those results off the search.  It is your fault that you changed your mind.  Just un-ignore them.

Comment: roflmaololorlyyarly !!!!!!11!!!1!!

Comment: Always nice to have things be intuitive. I guess some people do not agree though. That bothers me on a fundamental level.

Comment: @jjnguy: roflcopter

Comment: You're right, intuitive is nice - I'd also expect to be able to view 50 questions on a page regardless of which tags I have on my ignore list, but that doesn't happen. If I'm searching for something specifically, it's a pretty good bet that I want to see it.

Comment: It really comes down to degrees of intuition. I don't want to read java questions - hide them. Now, show me all the java questions. To continue hiding them is a little too literal. However, we programmers are notorious for taking things too literally, so perhaps that *is* the correct behavior.

Comment: @Andy: Not if you have gone out of your way to *ignore* it.

Comment: @Rich: Why do I still see the questions if they're *ignored*? The behaviour is inconsistent no matter which way you look at it.

Comment: @Andy Mikula: Because you haven't set it to hide ignored tags in your prefs.

Comment: 'Intuitive' is a myth.

Answer (score 0):

I agree - the way the page is set up, it seems that the ignored / interesting tags are for the questions page, not the whole site. I'd expect to be able to search for anything, regardless of whether I've told the questions view to show it.