# "What am I missing?" - exploring ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

I am guilty of having a long list of ignored tags. Every now and then, however, I wonder what's happening with a language or field I know little about, in the hope that perhaps I can discover something new (after all, one of the goals of Trilogy is learning, no?), and end up not ignoring it.

From the front page, I can click any ignored tag, which will, invariably, bring me to very useless blank page.

Would it be relevant/possible/useful to show what's being ignored, on clicking a particular ignored tag? The rule would be: if the tag selected is in the user's ignored tags, ignore all ignored tags.

Comment: Is your "hide ignored tags" preference turned on?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/clicking-on-an-ignored-tag-shows-no-results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untick the "hide ignored tags" option in the prefs tab of your profile.

[image: screenshot]