# Recent questions with Interesting/MyTags

Tags: discussion, questions, recent-activity

How to view the questions which were *discussed* today on SO, having tags in which I am either interested or participated (asked or answered)?

Comment: Unless you're talking about the watercooler: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/view-new-questions-marked-with-any-of-your-interesting-tags

Comment: no, i tried that, but the questions are not recent. There is no way to sort it according to recent changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to view [active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) questions with [hide ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43332/what-am-i-missing-exploring-ignored-tags/43333#43333) on.  There's pagination links at the bottom.

You will have to depend on your ignored tags instead of those you've participated in, though.

Comment: +1 quite close to what i want. But, this is ~(ignored tags) and i want  (interesting tags)

Comment: @nvl: Interesting tags will be highlighted, but yes, you're right about that.  Remember you can use wildcards (as that linked screenshot shows) in ignored tags, if that helps.