# Need better ways to handle ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

I am currently ignoring an odd 200 tags, growing about 5 a day.

Could Regex capability be added?

Also could interesting tags veto ignored tags?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/allow-wildcards-in-ignored-interesting-tags

Comment: @Kobi: Wildcards wont cut the crapload of BS tags that shows up  :)  But that is a start :)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/clicking-on-an-ignored-tag-shows-no-results

Comment: related to 3): [Allow assigning a score to tags to determine “interestingness”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62502/allow-assigning-a-score-to-tags-to-determine-interestingness), maybe assigning new tags with a user-specified default score, e.g. -5.

Comment: Yes, please. I would like to ignore anything starting with `minecraft` or `pokemon`, for example, on Arqade.