# Is there a way to "See" ignored questions without logging out?

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags, search

So I just did a search for some info on SO.  The result looked like this:

[image]

The above image should show that there is a problem.  Don't tell me there are 10 results and, with no indication why, show me 0 results.

Where are the 10 Questions?  Clearly I want to see them, I just did a search for them.  However, (I think) my Ignore tags are making them not show.

I know of 2 ways to see these questions:

1. **Log out**: I am not a web designer, would argue that it is never in a site's best interests to require a user to "De-authenticate" to use the site.
2. **Start removing things from my ignore list**: I have my ignore list for a good reason.  These are things I don't know about.  I ignore them when I am looking to answer questions.  I guess I can remove the offending from my ignore list, but I would rather not.

But I have to ask: Are either of these a good UI/user story?

Really this is a problem stemming from the fact that there are two uses for SO.  (1) Looking to give information (answering) and (2) looking for information (asking).

1. When I am looking to give info I want to only see questions that I know about.  This allows me to answer more questions and help more people in the time I have for Answering.
2. When I am looking for info, I need a broader set of results.  This is because I now am looking for info that I don't know much about.  This could be done with an "unfiltered" result set.

As I said above, the image should show that there is a problem.  Don't tell me there are 10 results and, with no indication why, show me 0 results.

I am now heading delete some ignored tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clicking on an ignored tag shows no results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/clicking-on-an-ignored-tag-shows-no-results)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of simply removing your ignored tags, consider just unmarking the "Hide Ignored Tags" preference. This way, it only takes one click to re-establish your normal preference, but until then you still get visibility to those questions.

[Here is a feature request which talks about a temporary disable for ignored questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/temporarily-disabling-ignore-tags). [An answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/temporarily-disabling-ignore-tags/36737#36737) suggests an option of having the "Hide ignored tags" on the right sidebar, which would let you flip this switch while you're browsing instead of needing to go to your profile page. If this problem bothers you a lot, I recommend providing support to at least one of those two ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Questions with ignored tags aren't hidden by default, just dimmed. They're only hidden if you've checked the "hide ignored tags" box in your preferences.